# The value of object's property is not being changed in the Local Storage in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building a shop in Ember with the list of products that are being added to Local Storage when the user clicks on the 
*add to cart* button. Each product is an object that has a property called `ordered_quantity`, I'm trying to change this property's value when the user tries to remove the product from the cart. (example: `ordered quantity: 8`, when the button is clicked it should be `7`).

I have the following code in my service file:

```
remove(item) {
  let new_arr = this.get('items');
  let elementIndex = new_arr.findIndex(obj => {
    return obj.id === item.id;
  });

  if (elementIndex !== -1) {
    new_arr[elementIndex].ordered_quantity = new_arr[elementIndex].ordered_quantity - 1;
  } 
  this.set('cart.items', new_arr);
}
```

I'm using Local Storage add-on (https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage#methods)

and I have the following action:

```
actions: {
  removeFromCart(){
    this.get('cart').remove(this.product);
  }
}
```

When I try to run the following code I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to update [object Object].ordered_quantity to "7", but it is being tracked by a tracking context, such as a template, computed property, or observer. In order to make sure the context updates properly, you must invalidate the property when updating it. You can mark the property as `@tracked`, or use `@ember/object#set` to do this.

I tried using the set function like this:

```
let updated = item.ordered_quantity - 1;
set(item, 'ordered_quantity', updated);
```

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject/set and the code worked with no errors as expected, but the value of my property `ordered_quantity` was not updated in the Local Storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to adapt the `set` function to your use-case:

```
remove(item) {
  let new_arr = this.get('items');
  let elementIndex = new_arr.findIndex(obj => {
    return obj.id === item.id;
  });

  if (elementIndex !== -1) {
    set(new_arr[elementIndex], 'ordered_quantity', new_arr[elementIndex].ordered_quantity - 1);
  } 
  this.set('cart.items', new_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based of @Lux's original answer (and to also update for the Ember 3.16+ era), I wanted to add that you could use functional programming patterns to clean things up a little bit:

If in your `cart` Service, items is `@tracked`, like so:

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

export default class CartService extends Service {
  @tracked items = [];
}
```

Note: assumes that `ordered_quantity` is *not* tracked.

```
remove(item) {
  for (let obj of this.items) {
    if (item.id !== obj.id) continue;

    // set must be used because quantity is not known to the tracking system
    set(obj, 'ordered_quantity', obj.ordered_quantity - 1);
  });

  // invalidate the reference on the card service so that all things that
  // reference cart.items re-compute
  this.cart.items = this.items;
}
```

Here is a live demo: https://ember-twiddle.com/e18433b851091b527512e27ae792640c?openFiles=components.demo%5C.js%2C

There is also a utility addon, which allows for more ergonomic interaction with arrays, objects, etc: https://github.com/pzuraq/tracked-built-ins

the above code would then look like this:

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { TrackedArray } from 'tracked-built-ins';

export default class CartService extends Service {
  @tracked items = new TrackedArray([]);
}
```

and then in your component:

```
remove(item) {
  for (let obj of this.items) {
    if (item.id !== obj.id) continue;

    // set must be used because quantity is not known to the tracking system
    set(obj, 'ordered_quantity', obj.ordered_quantity - 1);
  });
}
```

Here is a live demo: https://ember-twiddle.com/23c5a7efdb605d7b5fa9cd9da61c1294?openFiles=services.cart%5C.js%2C

You could then take it a step further, and add tracking to your "items".

so then your remove method would look like this:

```
remove(item) {
  for (let obj of this.items) {
    if (item.id !== obj.id) continue;

    obj.ordered_quantity = obj.ordered_quantity - 1;
  });
}
```

And here is a live demo: https://ember-twiddle.com/48c26e2e0f0e5f3ac7685e4bdc0eda4e?openFiles=components.demo%5C.js%2C